# How to use my-ciunit with MY_DB_active_rec.php

Tags: php, codeigniter, unit-testing, phpunit

I'm using my-ciunit for unit testing in Code Igniter however I have a unit test that fails because in my project i have extended the default active record class (My_DB_active_rec.php).

I now have a failing unit test because ciunit is not recognising that I have extended the class!

How can I make sure that ciunit loads my 'MY_DB_active_rec.php' as it does in my main project.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Extending your MY_Loader in CIU_Loader.php instead of CI_Loader :

class CIU_Loader extends MY_Loader { ..... }